# jssor slider + sharepoint 2010

Tags: html, sharepoint, jssor

I am try to use two jssor sliders in sharepoint 2010.

Have created 2 webparts in sharepoint 2010 and using CEWP to reference html. 
left webpart should use one jssor slider with different subject & pics. 
right webpart should use another jssor slider with different subject & pics.

I tried, but only one would show up when we publish the page. Not both ?

LEFT HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;">

    <!-- The following codes demostrate jssor slider work independently without any other javascript library. -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="March 2016/js/jssor.slider-20.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider-20.debug.js instead for debug -->
    <script>
        jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
            ];

            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                $Cols: 8,
                $SpacingX: 8,
                $SpacingY: 8,
                $Align: 360
              }
            };

            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 550);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
    </script>

    <style>

        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssora05l                  (normal)
        .jssora05r                  (normal)
        .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('March 2016/img/a17.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
        .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
        .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
        .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
        .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
        .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

        /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
        /*
        .jssort01 .p            (normal)
        .jssort01 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
        .jssort01 .p.pav        (active)
        .jssort01 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
        */
        .jssort01 .p {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
        }

        .jssort01 .t {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }

        .jssort01 .w {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .jssort01 .c {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border: #fff 2px solid;
            box-sizing: content-box;
           background: url('March 2016/img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
            _background: none;
        }

        .jssort01 .pav .c {
            top: 10px;
            _top: 0px;
            left: 10px;
            _left: 0px;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border: #000 0px solid;
            _border: #fff 2px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        .jssort01 .p:hover .c {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border: #fff 1px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        .jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border: #fff 2px solid;
        }

        * html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
            /* ie quirks mode adjust */
            width /**/: 80px;
            height /**/: 80px;
        }

    </style>


    <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 5px; left: 0px; width: 607px; height: 367px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #1874cd;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('March 2016/img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 5px; left: 50px; width: 507px; height: 267px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/01.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-01.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/02.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-02.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/03.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/04.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/05.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-05.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/06.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-06.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/07.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-07.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/08.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-08.jpg" />
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
        <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:550px;height:100px;" data-autocenter="1">
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
                <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                    <div class="w">
                        <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:100px;left:1px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:100px;right:1px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
      <!--  <a href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Jssor Slider</a>    -->
    </div>
   <script>
        jssor_1_slider_init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have enough information to know whether this will fix your problem, but the content link property of a CEWP should be the path to a file containing an HTML **fragment**, not an entire HTML page, since that fragment will be inserted within your page. If you're trying to embed an HTML page, consider using a Page Viewer web part or an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually building an API that integrates Jssor with SharePoint 2010 and 2013. It will be able to handle Ajax calls and dynamically build out the DOM, and make it easier to set properties for the widget. I also have a couple plans, but don't want to give them away just yet. ;)

You can have as many sliders as you want on the page. Each ID has to be unique in both JavaScript and HTML.

Add this to the right CEWP:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;">

    <!-- The following codes demostrate jssor slider work independently without any other javascript library. -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="March 2016/js/jssor.slider-20.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider-20.debug.js instead for debug -->
    <script>
        jssor_2_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_2_SlideshowTransitions = [
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
            ];

            var jssor_2_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: jssor_2_SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                $Cols: 8,
                $SpacingX: 8,
                $SpacingY: 8,
                $Align: 360
              }
            };

            var jssor_2_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_2", jssor_2_options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_2_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 550);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
    </script>

    <style>

        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssora05l                  (normal)
        .jssora05r                  (normal)
        .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('March 2016/img/a17.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
        .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
        .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
        .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
        .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
        .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

        /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
        /*
        .jssort01 .p            (normal)
        .jssort01 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
        .jssort01 .p.pav        (active)
        .jssort01 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
        */
        .jssort01 .p {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
        }

        .jssort01 .t {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }

        .jssort01 .w {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .jssort01 .c {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border: #fff 2px solid;
            box-sizing: content-box;
           background: url('March 2016/img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
            _background: none;
        }

        .jssort01 .pav .c {
            top: 10px;
            _top: 0px;
            left: 10px;
            _left: 0px;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border: #000 0px solid;
            _border: #fff 2px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        .jssort01 .p:hover .c {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border: #fff 1px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        .jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border: #fff 2px solid;
        }

        * html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
            /* ie quirks mode adjust */
            width /**/: 80px;
            height /**/: 80px;
        }

    </style>


    <div id="jssor_2" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 5px; left: 0px; width: 607px; height: 367px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #1874cd;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('March 2016/img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 5px; left: 50px; width: 507px; height: 267px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/01.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-01.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/02.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-02.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/03.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/04.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/05.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-05.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/06.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-06.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/07.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-07.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="March 2016/img/08.png" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="March 2016/img/thumb-08.jpg" />
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
        <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:550px;height:100px;" data-autocenter="1">
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
                <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                    <div class="w">
                        <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:100px;left:1px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:100px;right:1px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
      <!--  <a href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Jssor Slider</a>    -->
    </div>
   <script>
        jssor_2_slider_init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code could use some cleanup (all I did was change the IDs). It's best to remove the redundancy of reusable functions and css code.

Also, with SP2010, I would recommend separating the script from the html & css. Save the script into a .js file and add a  tag to your CEWP before the html. This will prevent SharePoint from "correcting" what it thinks is wrong.